# converting user-item-rating list to user-item-matrix with pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is how user-item-rating list looks like as a pandas dataframe.

```
   item_id  rating user_id
0  aaaaaaa       5       X
1  bbbbbbb       2       Y
2  ccccccc       5       Z
3  ddddddd       1       T
```

This how I create user-item-matrix in pandas and it only takes a couple of seconds with real dataset (about 500k row):

```
user_item_matrix = df.pivot(index = 'user_id', columns ='item_id', values = 'rating')

item_id  aaaaaaa  bbbbbbb  ccccccc  ddddddd
user_id                                    
T            NaN      NaN      NaN      1.0
X            5.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
Y            NaN      2.0      NaN      NaN
Z            NaN      NaN      5.0      NaN
```

I am trying this approach to achieve same result with pyspark dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

df.groupby('user_id') \
  .pivot('item_id') \
  .agg(first('rating'))
```

But it takes ages to complete with real data. Is there a smarter/faster way to achieve this? Basically I am trying to build an user-item matrix from an user-item-rating list.

Comment: i would have expected that to work :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative approach that is RDD based.

```
rating_list = [['aaa',5.0,'T'],['bbb',5.0,'U'],['ccc',5.0,'V'],['ddd',5.0,'W'],['eee',5.0,'X']]
df = sc.parallelize(rating_list).toDF(['item_id','rating','user_id'])
df.show()

+-------+------+-------+
|item_id|rating|user_id|
+-------+------+-------+
|    aaa|   5.0|      T|
|    bbb|   5.0|      U|
|    ccc|   5.0|      V|
|    ddd|   5.0|      W|
|    eee|   5.0|      X|
+-------+------+-------+


items = df.select('item_id').rdd.map(lambda data:data.item_id).collect()
item_len = len(items)

def transformRating(item_id,rating,user_id):
    rating_list = [rating if ele == item_id else None for ele in items]
    return ([user_id]+rating_list)

df1 = (df.rdd.map(lambda data:(data.item_id,data.rating,data.user_id))
             .map(lambda (item,rat,uid):transformRating(item,rat,uid))
             .toDF(['uid']+items))

df1.show()

+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|uid| aaa| bbb| ccc| ddd| eee|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|  T| 5.0|null|null|null|null|
|  U|null| 5.0|null|null|null|
|  V|null|null| 5.0|null|null|
|  W|null|null|null| 5.0|null|
|  X|null|null|null|null| 5.0|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Now I would assume that one user might rate multiple items. In that case you might need to reduce the RDD based on user_id and combine rating. It will just be one more reduceByKey statement before .toDF and you should get a df like that.

Comment: There has got to be a more concise way to do this. Recommender systems and matrix factorization methods, especially, need to accomplish this effect. I would imagine that a more streamlined approach does exist.

Comment: Also, this throws an error; python or at least google colab, does not see `lamba (item,rat,uid)` as acceptable.

Comment: @mjake Depends on the python version. At the time of writing this worked with python 2.7 or python 3.1 or something don't remember.

You can easily change it to (lambda data: data[0], data[1], data[2]) and should work fine!

Comment: @mjake The question was asked 2 years ago. Since then pyspark has evolved and you have function such as explode and others... you can explore that. There is for sure an easy way to do this with Dataframes now.